# Login_user fails to get userid with NotImplementedError

Tags: flask-login

My app fails whenever I call login_user with the error 
"NotImplementedError: No `id` attribute - override `get_id`". Why does this fail?

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
if current_user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
form = LoginForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
    if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
        login_user(user, remember=True)
    else:
        flash('Login Unsuccessful. Please check email and password', 'danger')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
return render_template('login.html', title='login', form=form)

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(userid):
    return User.query.get(userid)

class User(UserMixin):
    def get_id(self):
        return self.userid

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    userid = db.Column(db.String(50), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String(200), unique=True, nullable=False)
    designation = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    dateofjoin = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(200), unique=True, nullable=False)
    address = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    mobile = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)

   def __repr__(self):
       return f"User('{self.userid}','{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.designation}', '{self.password}')"
```

Comment: Add more details on the error. Put up an exception trace if possible. It will be easier to find the possible error.

Answer (score 0):

In your User model rename primary_key 'userid' to 'id'. Update the db and try again. The get_id method looks for 'id'. It is hardcoded into flask-login. Or you can edit get_id method itself in flask_login's mixin.py module. But I am not sure it won't break somewhere else.

```
def get_id(self):
    try:
        return text_type(self.id) # Rename 'id' to 'userid'
    except AttributeError:
        raise NotImplementedError('No `id` attribute - override `get_id`')
```